# How to export a dictionary of classes in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a TypeScript definition for a module that exports an object containing groups of classes. It looks like this:

```js
class A1 {}
class A2 {}
class B1 {}
class B2 {}

const api = {
  a: { A1, A2 },
  b: { B1, B2 },
};

const x: api.a.A1 = new api.a.A1();
// ------^ TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'api'.
```

I want to export this structure from my module as both values and types, so I can use the same notation. But you can see the problem above: it requires me to have a namespace for that. Is there a way to achieve that without manually repeating the `api` object structure (it's quite complicated) as a namespace?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not [make it a namespace to start with](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEIYEskG8BQS9IgA8YB7AJwBclRJYFkQtd8WjTKl4AbEKKJAIIBGLEgC+zFnjbkq3XvwEAmURMnj1MjjWhxESAEZMp+eXyQAhEZg0m8Z-hZU2JLCWvglgUKoQBcKOgAdCBBwkgAvNQQAO6BaCFhQgAUAJQA3EA)?  It's still an object.

Comment: Also please note that the guidelines for [ask] say not "to post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question" instead.

Comment: @jcalz Thank you, that worked like a charm! I'll update the question.

Comment: I have also finally found it in the original docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html#aliases

Answer (score 0):

The valid type annotation for the instance will look like:

```
class A1 {
    foo = "asd";
}
class A2 {}
class B1 {}
class B2 {}
const api = {
    a: { A1, A2 },
    b: { B1, B2 }
};
const x: InstanceType<typeof api["a"]["A1"]> = new api.a.A1();
console.log(x.foo); // asd
```

The type declaration for X is absolutely unnecessary - it will be inferred when you instantiate. So the following one is much cleaner and will work:

```
const x = new api.a.A1();
```